# how to update redis list in C#

Tags: c#, redis

My code sample is

```
RedisClient redisClient = new RedisClient("", 6379);
var redisUsers = redisClient.GetTypedClient<User>();
IRedisList<User> OrderCash = redisUsers.Lists["Order_Cash|123|1"];

 var Ocash = new User { OrderI_lngId = 123, OrderI_mnyInvTotal = 44, Item_strID = "Hii", Booking_lngId = 12345, OrderI_strTempTransId = "4", Booking_strId = "TOTAL12345", Item_lngId = 2, ItemVar_intSequence = 1 };


OrderCash.Add(Ocash);
```

Through this i tried to  insert. Its working fine.

I am able to retrieve the value for the same key. Now i need to update some value in that.
I tried this way ,

```
OrderCash.Where(o => o.Item_lngId == bsonDoc.TryGetValue("lngItemId", 0).ToLong() && o.ItemVar_intSequence == bsonDoc.TryGetValue("intItemVarSequence", 0).ToInt()).ForEach(objCash => {
                    objCash.OrderI_mnyInvTotal = bsonDoc.TryGetValue("mnyInvTotal", 0).ToFloat();
                    objCash.Item_strID = bsonDoc.TryGetValue("strItemId", "").ToStr();
                    objCash.Booking_lngId = bsonDoc.TryGetValue("lngBookingId", 0).ToLong();
                    objCash.Booking_strId = bsonDoc.TryGetValue("strBookingId", "").ToStr();
                    objCash.OrderI_strTempTransId = bsonDoc.TryGetValue("strTempTransId", "").ToStr();

                });
```

But its not updating the value remains in the **OrderCash** object while in debugging ?

I need to update some value in that key.

How to achieve that ??

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

```
var lstTemp = redisUsers.Lists["Order_Cash|123|1"].ToList();

foreach(var item in lstTemp){

// Update here
}
```

then in the list pop the current item and add this updated list.